# ggplot2: custom categorical labels on a numerical x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a heavy user of ggplot2 but somehow I'm struggling to solve this problem.

For example, I have a plot like following from ggplot2

[image]

Here I want to remove x-axis labels and add "start" and "end" respectively at 0 and 100. I've seen some posts here on how to add custom labels to ggplot2 but it didn't help me to solve my problem. I was wondering is it possible yet all somehow.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `scale_x_continuous`'s arguments `breaks` and `labels` here.

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(x = -10:110,
                 y = rnorm(121))

ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100),
                     labels = c("start", "end"))
```

[image]